# How do I Run/Debug a private function in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

The GAS editor is able to `Run function` and `Debug function`, but *only* if the function isn't private (i.e. doesn't have `_` appended to the end of the function name). This is a problem, because if the function name isn't private, it's publicly exposed when the script is published as an add-on.

The workaround is the remove the underscore, run/debug the function, and then re-append the underscore. This is not hard, but it smells. When I am forced to do this, I am convinced I am not doing something the correct way. What is the correct way?

Comment: One options is: 1) have a GS file for testing, and call the private function from the test function `function testMyFunc() {privateFuncName_()};`  Other options **without** using debug is to log your variable values out to StackDriver or your own spreadsheet and 2) Create a menu item in the document just for testing, and link the private function name to the menu item.  3) Run your code as the user would be running it.  Unfortunately, if you want to step through the code, the only other option might be option one.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm doing Apps Script development in the web interface (which imposes these limits) I tend to collect some "test" functions which I use during development. In my case I'm usually trying to feed different values to functions which take arguments, but you could do the same. As a bonus, it's easy to remove these helper functions when you publish the script since you don't have to around changing the name of things.

A silly example:

```
// TODO(jjjjoe) remove these before publishing

function testFoo() { _foo(); }

function testBar() { _bar(); }

function testAll() {
    _foo(); _bar();
}

function _foo() {
    // Spend The Most Curious Thing's money
}

function _bar() {
    // Send lots of emails
}
```